# How can i match two different List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 GameObject and each other has a lot of child. This two GameObject same as same except some child's exist or child's position. I found each child's name.
And also I found locations info for each item. Then I compared this Lists and i found relocated, exist, added and removed items. I want to match with relocated items with names. How can I do that?

**On Project1**

```
List<string> existItems = GetNames().Intersect(revisedBasicProject4.GetNames4()).ToList();
List<Vector3> comparePosition = GetLocations().Except(revisedBasicProject4.GetLocations()).ToList();

        foreach (var item in existItems)
        {
            isExist = true;
        }

        if (isExist)
        {
            foreach (var item in comparePosition)
            {
                    Debug.Log("RELOCATED ITEMS :" +item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the `isExist = true;` supposed to do in a loop? If just want to know if there is any item use either  `existItems.Count > 0` or since you are using Linq anyway simply `existItems.Any()` ... I don't fully understand what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Either way why separate the information into different collections? It would be way better to return the actual class items and then filter on them .. this way you would have both informations (names, locations , etc?)  still strictly coupled to each other in one instance of your class in your case probably either `Transform` or `GameObject`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood what you meant correctly or not, but you can use the following code

```
    List<string> existItems = GetNames().Intersect(revisedBasicProject4.GetNames4()).ToList();
    List<Vector3> comparePosition = GetLocations().Except(revisedBasicProject4.GetLocations()).ToList();

    foreach (var item in existItems)
        foreach (var li in comparePosition)
            if (item.(...) == li.(...)) {
                Debug.Log("RELOCATED ITEMS :" + item);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo and https://stackoverflow.com/users/13922490/mohammad-asadi - You want to store names and locations together, so use [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html):

Then, you can compare your revisedBasicProject4 Transforms with the current class like so:

```
foreach(var transform in GetTransforms())
{
    foreach(var revisedBasicProject4Transform in revisedBasicProject4.GetTransforms())
    {
        if ( transform.name == revisedBasicProject4Transform.name 
             && transform.position != revisedBasicProject4Transform.position)
        {
            Debug.Log("RELOCATED ITEM : " + transform.name);
        }
    }
}
```

If you find this is taking forever (because you have millions of Transforms, you may be able to optimise this by doing the following:

```
var transforms = new List<Transform>(GetTransforms());
var otherTransforms= new List<Transform>(revisedBasicProject4.GetTransforms());

for(var i = 0; i < transforms.Count; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < otherTransforms.Count; j++)
    {
        if ( transforms[i].name == otherTransforms[j].name )
        {
            if ( transforms[i].position != otherTransforms[j].position )
                Debug.Log("RELOCATED ITEM : " + transforms[i].name);
            otherTransforms.RemoveAt(j); //We found it so remove it from our temporary "otherTransforms" list
            break; //We found it so move on to the next "transforms" item
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't think you want a custom struct but rather the original source class directly which seems to be `Transform` though ...

Comment: Ah. Yes you're right, There's an inherited name property on 'Transform' - I will amend my answer